# Testing a web service by returning a string of data in a web application form

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I've got a web service but need to know how to test it in a windows application form.

here is the start of the service. Would I put the form code inside a button, or just return it in a label? Not exactly overly clued into c# or .net I've called the web service succesfully thougha nd just need to return the string to make sure encryption is working.

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="UserEncryptionLink.EncryptUserLink" %>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;




namespace UserEncryptionLink
{
/// <summary>
   /// This Web Service is to encrypt user details and display them in the URL when  they   click on a link taking them to InfoExchange
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = " Webspace name")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
//To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the    following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]







public class EncryptUserLink : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
[WebMethod]
public void TestCypher()
{
    var key = "12345";
    var vector = "12345";
    var username = "YOURDOMAIN\\YOURUSERNAME";
    var url = "sitename.com";
    var it = GetSingleSignOnUrl(url, username, key, vector);
}
```

And my form

Yeah I've got my form referencing the service, it looks like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using FormForEncrypt.nameofURL;
using System.Net;



namespace FormForEncrypt
{


public partial class EncryptForm : Form
{


    public EncryptForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    // creates an instance of the web service as a member of the class, will put it down below, doesn't seem to work though declared in the using statement
    private nameofURL.EncryptUserLink userform = new nameofUrl.EncryptUserLink();



    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

    private void testButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        //method to send on button click, then recieve the string to show it works, it should come out as http://CLIENTNAME.info-exchange.com/yyyyMMddHHmmssDomainUsername 

        //create instances of the details


        string[] it;

        //send string

        //recieve string and display, it must display the same as what was sent. 


    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you want to check the webservice is working ok, browse to it locally - you should be able to see and call each method. As for where you put the code in your form - if it's none trivial it should be in a business/data access/services layer - otherwise the button handler is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean if you should put the form code inside a button or return it in a label?
Webservices don't have concepts of forms or label or anything. They are just services... no forms, no controls... just somewhat "raw code" waiting to be served up by invoking it and your hosting protocol (such as IIS or WAS or self hosting app) takes care of spinning it up and running the service.

interms of calling it... well, it depends where you want to call it from your application. Could be on a button click, could be on a timer, could be on a form load... depends on you and your application logic.

your current web method, TestChypher, does not return anything at the moment. you need to, I am guessing, return a bool value to indicate if the string matches or not?

again, depends on you and what you want to return. if you wanted to return a string, change the method signature to return a string - so change "void" to "string" and return back, in that method, a string you want to return back.

example - short snip:

```
[WebMethod]
public void SayHello()
{
   return "Hello";
}
```

Comment: I mean I created a web form that is calling the service, I now want to return the fields to make sure the service is encrypting and will display the encrypted URL, I don't really have a clue how to progress with this, how would I get the web form I've created that is calling the Web Service to return the URL string that I want?

Comment: following my example, its straight forward. have you managed to call your webservice from your webform on say a button click? if not, you need to add a reference to the webservice in your project, then you should be able to access it as the methods available will be exposed and you can call it. also, update your question tag to include ASP.NET.

Comment: so you have no code calling the service? simply do userform.TestCypher() on your click. that will call the service (but wont return anything as its a void method)

Comment: Yeah, I've been told to just return a string to show that the encryption is working, I'm not sure how I'd do that. it'd be the encryption url after the actual URL I think.

Comment: did you read my answer on how to modify the method to return something back? :) change "void" to "string" and return back the string you want to return back from the webservice.

Comment: so while on the form it would be like,
    
    call webservice and name variable userform
    
    [WebMethod]
    public void SayHello(userform)
    {
       return string it;
    }

That would return the string it from the service which is the username, dates and ID ?

Comment: so while on the form it would be like,
     
      call webservice and name variable userform
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

        private void testButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
           
        {
           


        

That would return the string it from the service which is the username, dates and ID ?

Comment: it will return whatever the webservice returns you.

Comment: so would I have to add
    [WebMethod]
    public void returnData()
    {
   return string it;
    }

Somewhere into the web service then show that into the form?

Comment: as i said before a few times, the method will not return you anything. it is marked as void.

Comment: Thanks for the help, so it should be like this? (if I can call SingleSignOnUrl from the service which is being called itself). This is inside the form


        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public string GiveString()
        {

            return "SingleSignOnUrl";
        }

        private void EncryptForm_Load(EncryptForm, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = GiveString(SingleSignOnUrl);
        }
    }

Comment: right, pretty much. you need to do userform.GiveString(SingleSignOnUrl);. remember you need to call the webservice which exists in the webservice reference, userform.

Comment: Cheers, you've been a help.